# ' ../ ' not working in php

Tags: php, require

I have a file frontend/file.php and I want to include a file (using require function) in database/file2.php (frontend and database folders are in the same directory)
I wrote this code:

```
require('../database/file2.php');
```

But it isnt working, please help

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: *"Not working"*  isn't much to go on; check for errors.

Comment: It says file not found @ Fred -ii-

Comment: that will depend on many factors. 1) If you're on a \*NIX system. Filenames/folders are case-sensitive. 2) The path is incorrect or that you need to use a full system path. Check your logs and if this is db-related, check for errors for that also.

Comment: I already answered today to a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42690997/4265352). Take a look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42691425/4265352). Voting to close as duplicate (this question was asked dozens of times on [so].)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux/php require parent directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634652/linux-php-require-parent-directory)

Comment: @user7324674 Did you try the answer below, how'd it work out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../database/file2.php';
```

This will ensure the file is located relative to the current path, read more about this here.

[PHP Require Guide](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)